# Eevee renders reflected lights with wrong z-buffer

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection

I have noticed that Eevee reflected lights (in my case are visible areas) appear ahead other objects which are closer to the reflecting surface.

This is one example

[image]

is this a bug or there is something in the settings? Could it be a problem in the reflection plane?

Edit: I distanced the light from the reflecting surface and added a cube to see if this affected also other objects in the ray path. It seem that for big distanced the light start to disappear (blending) behind the other objects.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the angle, you can also have shadows on the mirrored lamp image. Strange. Don't know if this is an Eevee limitation. Have you been further on the subject?

Comment: @lemon I opened a task at developer.blender.org, let see how this is considered. I have also tried to change both eevee and material settings, but that "ghost' is still there.

Comment: Could you indicate the link of the task, please?

Comment: here is it https://developer.blender.org/T67788