# Glass - How to make visible light source behind (eevee)

Tags: shaders, glass

I'm trying to build a simple metro train. My goal is to make the windows transparent so I can see from the inside the lights that are out of the train. I tried to play around with the settings that are within the Glass shader but I cannot do it. I get the effect only on the outer side. Im a newbie.

This is from the inside:

[image]

This is from the outside:

[image]

As you can see I get a reflection which I dont want. I want only the glass to be transparent from both sides.

Comment: maybe this will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148559/how-to-hide-lamp-reflection-in-eevee

Comment: Basically add texture/material to the glass object.

Comment: You have transparent glass if you can see inside. From outside you see black because of black environment, but you have invisible the light behind the glass, right? I changed title. If Im wrong change it back. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Light source behind a glass (Eevee)

[image]

To see through a glass enable

- *Properties editor* > *Render Properties* tab > *Screen Space Reflections* > *Refractions*
- and under *Material Properties* > *Settings* > *Screen Space Refraction*

[image]

To see a light source like a *Point*

- add a *Cube* (in location of light) with Principle Volume shader
- decrease *Density* to 0.1 or lower and *Anisotropy* increase to 0.9

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you all! Gonna try your solutions.

Comment: If the answer solved your issue consider mark it as accepted (grey big checkmark under vote arrows), it is only your privilege to do and you can uncheck any time too. It is useful for others to see it from main list it was solved. Thank you