# How to Hide light sources in mirror Blender Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, reflection

[image]how can I hide mirror light sources.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any solution for the moment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148559/how-to-hide-lamp-reflection-in-eevee ... you can decrease its Radius but it's still visible at 0

Comment: Thanks Friend it is working. Thanks a lot

Comment: So what solution have you found?

Comment: I can hide this mirror reflection light source. Thanks.

Comment: Yes so please give the solution in the Your Answer field so that if anyone has the same question he can find a solution  ;)

Comment: Ok friend I do it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Light Properties - Specular Value = 0, Radius = 0

That's fix's my Problem.